# Cygwin-X does not start

Tags: cygwin, x11

I tried to Start X from Cygwin, but it gave the following error:

$ `startxwin`

```
C:/cygwin64/bin/xauth.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygXmuu-1.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
C:/cygwin64/bin/xauth.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygXmuu-1.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
C:/cygwin64/bin/xauth.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygXmuu-1.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
C:/cygwin64/bin/xauth.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygXmuu-1.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
C:/cygwin64/bin/xauth.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygXmuu-1.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
C:/cygwin64/bin/XWin.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygxcb-ewmh-2.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
C:/cygwin64/bin/xauth.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygXmuu-1.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

$ `cygcheck -c Cygwin`

```
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
cygwin               3.3.6-1        OK
```

[The current version of cygwin is 3.3.6-1](https://cygwin.com/pipermail/cygwin-announce/2022-September/010707.html)

$ `apt-cyg install xauth`

```
Package xauth is already installed, skipping
```

$ `xauth -v`

```
C:/cygwin64/bin/xauth.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygXmuu-1.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

$ `apt-cyg remove  xauth`

```
Removing xauth
Package xauth removed
```

$ `apt-cyg install xauth`

```
Installing xauth
xauth-1.1.2-1.tar.xz: OK
Unpacking...
Package xauth installed
```

$ `xauth -v`

```
C:/cygwin64/bin/xauth.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygXmuu-1.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Is there any package to install `cygXmuu-1.dll` and `cygxcb-ewmh-2.dll` through `apt-cyg`?

Thanks.

Comment: Use the most recent version of the cygwin setup.exe installer downloaded from cygwin.com. It is the only official and supported way to install cygwin. Always install all pending updates. If that does not work, try to reinstall the xauth package.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and  I have modifed post based on your comment. Of course, it is installed from `cygwin.com`. I tried to remove and reinstalled `xauth` package. **xauth** command does not show version info.

Comment: You are still using `apt-cyg`. You must use the official cygwin installer found at `https://www.cygwin.com/install.html` when you have problems with unofficial install methods. I always use `setup.exe` to keep my cygwin install up to date. I have not used `startxwin` in several years, however it just worked and, in an xterm window, ` xauth -V` gives `1.1.2`.

Comment: I removed `C:\cygwin64` and cleaned up the Registry entries for `Cygwin`. Reinstalled `Cygwin` again.  Now `startxwin` works. I recollect now that, some time back, I upgraded `Cygwin` to the latest version. Probably that has caused this problem. @Doug, thank you so much for your help. Can you convert your comments into an answer so that I shall approve it.